# How to remove border from DropDownSearch in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, drop-down-menu, dropdown, flutter-web

I am using drop down search to fetch and display the list of items from firebase but I am getting a form field box by default with this widget. I wan't to remove this as it is not matching with my UI can anyone help me in this.

Widget I used is https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search

I am talking about the box that appears in this.
[image]

If you suggest me to use another widget then please also tell how to enable search oprtion in the same

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove border around **dropdown** element, set **dropdownSearchDecoration**  to `InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none)`:

```dart
              DropdownSearch<String>(
                dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                // ...
              )
```

Answer (score 2):

The DropdownSearch widget border have its **default** input border style. To remove, we need to **overwrite** it with our **own** inputBorder by setting the border to **InputBorder.none**.

**Code**

```
DropdownSearch<String>(
  enabled: true,
  items: yourList,
  dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
      dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(border:InputBorder.none),
              ),
  onChanged: (myVal) {},
  selectedItem: yourOwnSetValue
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
                          dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                          
                          ),
```